# Why does the document.addEventListener event run after document.body.addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, jquery

why does the .body event fire first and the document event fire next, explain with details?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
  <img src="https://www.wallpapertip.com/wmimgs/83-838381_html-wallpaper-background-code-coding-tags.jpg"
    width="100%" />
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('click', function () {
      console.log('The document was clicked');
    });

    document.body.addEventListener('click', function () {
      console.log('The document body was clicked');
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 concepts you need to know in order to understand why this happens:

- Bubbling
- Capturing

Bubbling is the default behaviour when adding event listeners. With bubbling, when an event happens on an element, it runs any handlers on that element first, and then bubbles up the DOM tree to it's parents.

Capturing happens in the opposite direction. The parents handler is first invoked before travelling to its children.

The *document* is the highest level parent in the DOM tree; therefore, *body* is a *child* of the *document*

If you wish to swap the default behaviour of bubbling, and want the parent elements handler to fire prior to it's children, the `addEventListener` method takes an optional third parameter:

```
addEventListener(event, function, true)  // <--- true states to enable capturing
```